# How can I transfer a playlist straight to my PC?

Tags: file-transfer, music, android-pc

The key is that my music files are all over the place in separate folder in my phone. It would be too time consuming to sift through every folder and pull out the individual song files that are in my playlist, not to mention some of the files are weirdly named so I'd end up missing some.

I'm trying to move just the songs that are in said playlist so I can burn them to a CD. The music app on my LGG4 let me export the playlist into an ".m4u" file but I'm not sure what this does or if it even helps. Any guidance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A link to a solution that someone had for a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1224932

Comment: @user149463 - how do you think this will help? It is just a for loop putting together some files with a given extension. Please explain.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the help of 2 free apps (with Android 4.1.2 on a Samsung S3 mini), because Android can't do this directly:

- Total Commander
- Playlist Backup

Install them from the Google Playstore, then continue as follows:

1. With Playlist Backup, export the Playlist as text file. Store it in a temp folder on your mobile.
2. To copy the MP3 files contained in the playlist, open the playlist in Android's built in player, then select "Send via" in the context menu. Select all files. Then, a list of apps is shown. Select Total Commander. In Total Commander, pick the local temporary folder (on your mobile) to copy the files into.
3. After Total Commander has copied the files, connect the mobile with your PC and copy the temporary folder to the PCs harddisk (containing the playlist text file and the MP3 files)

Finally edit the playlist file to adapt the paths in it so the MP3files are found by the PC player software (e.g. WinAmp or any other MP3 player which supports playlists).

Comment: Let me add that this solution, which relies on two 3rd party tools, is limited to a selection of 100 entries at a time. So, if you have bigger playlists, you have to do it with the 1st set of 100 files, then the 2nd set of 100 files and so on. However, the playlist itself can be extracted in one go.